# Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, javabeans

I am getting below errors while running my spring project.

> 2020-06-07 11:43:24.544 ERROR 15544 --- [         task-1]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
>   during pool initialization.
>
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]  at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
>   [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
>   [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
>   [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]   at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
>   [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
>   [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]    at      at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221] Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link
>   failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     ... 33 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: jdbc    at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_221]   at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:132)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]     ... 36 common frames
>   omitted
>
> 2020-06-07 11:43:24.545  WARN 15544 --- [         task-1]
>   o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain
>   connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   2020-06-07 11:43:24.554  WARN 15544 --- [           main]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]:
>   Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in
>   com.pasanyasara.ProductManager.ProductRepository defined in
>   @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
>   JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
>   resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean
>   property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] Related
>   cause:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined
>   in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path
>   resource [    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:167)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>   [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.pasanyasara.ProductManager.ProductManagerApplication.main(ProductManagerApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named
>   'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry'
>   available     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 18 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named
>   'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry'
>   available     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:456)
>   ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 40 common frames
>   omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

**application.properties**

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
>   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://jdbc:3306/salesdb
>   spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=

**Product.java**

```
 package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

 import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.InjectionClassLoader;

 import javax.persistence.Entity; import
 javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import
 javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id;

 @Entity public class Product {
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private String brand;
     private String madein;
     private float price;

     public Product() {
         super();
     }

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy  = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     public Long getId() {
         return id;
     }

     public void setId(Long id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

     public String getBrand() {
         return brand;
     }

     public void setBrand(String brand) {
         this.brand = brand;
     }

     public String getMadein() {
         return madein;
     }

     public void setMadein(String madein) {
         this.madein = madein;
     }

     public float getPrice() {
         return price;
     }

     public void setPrice(float price) {
         this.price = price;
     }
```

}

**ProductRepository.java** (interface)

```
 package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

 import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

 public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>
 {

 }
```

**ProductService.java**

```
     package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

     import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before; import
     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import
     org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

     import java.util.List;

     @Service 
     public class ProductService {
         @Autowired
         private ProductRepository repo;


         public List<Product> listAll(){
             return repo.findAll();
         }

         public void save(Product product)
         {
             repo.save(product);
         }

         public Product get(Long id){
             return repo.findById(id).get();
         }

         public void delete(Long id){
             repo.deleteById(id);
         } 
}
```

**AppController.java**

```
 package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import
 org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier; import
 org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; import
 org.springframework.ui.Model; import
 org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


 import java.util.List;

 @Controller public class AppController {

     //@Qualifier(ProductService)

     @Autowired
     private ProductService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
     public String viewHomePage(Model model){
         List<Product> listProducts = service.listAll();
         model.addAttribute("listProducts",listProducts);
         return "index";
     }
 }
```

**ProductManagerApplication.java** (Main class)

```
 package com.pasanyasara.ProductManager;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; import
 org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

 @SpringBootApplication public class ProductManagerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductManagerApplication.class, args);   }

 }
```

Comment: Is your mysql server accessible from the location you are the running the application?Also your url jdbc:mysql://jdbc:3306/salesdb is using jdbc as the dns for mysql server. Verify that this dns name is getting resolved from your location. You can use telnet jdbc 3306 command  for the same.

Comment: yes. MySQL running on local

Comment: if your mysql is running on local why don't you use the url like this jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salesdb

Comment: Did you add mysql jdbc dependency to your build script?